# Access a dynamic name variable with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use a function `.isChecked()` from the ***OnsenUI framework*** on a `name`.

My HTML is dynamic, so the number always changes. It's like:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="switch__input switch--list-item__input 
ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-not-empty" ng-model="model" name="menu_switch_35399">
```

If I run it like:

```
console.log(menu_switch_35399.isChecked());
```

it WORKS FINE and returns `true` or `false` correctly. But when I try to access it dynamically, it doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

I tried:

```
var test = $('[name=menu_switch_' + id + ']');
// console.log returns menu_switch_35399
```

And then running

```
test.isChecked()
```

but that doesn't work. I also tried:

```
$('[name=menu_switch_' + id + ']').isChecked()
```

And that also doesn't work.

The error is always

> Uncaught TypeError: test.isChecked is not a function

How can I access this dynamic variable?

Comment: You're missing some quotes: `$('[name="menu_switch_' + id + '"]')`
https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: Did you mean `.checked` or `.prop('checked')` by chance? Assuming your ID variable is valid, it should work.

Comment: @VVV did not work unfortunately. `console.log($('[name="menu_switch_' + id + '"]').isChecked());` doesn't work.

Comment: `$('[name=menu_switch_' + id + ']').is(":checked")` OR `$('[name=menu_switch_' + id + ']')[0].checked`

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef That worked! All the others didn't. If you create an answer I will accept it. Thank you also to ChewySalmon .checked was close but didn't work.

Comment: Glad it helps @moomoo .. you're totally welcome -- Have a great day :-)